# Gurobi Python solve interrupted without error code

Tags: python-2.7, callback, mathematical-optimization, gurobi

When I do not use callback, I can solve problems with medium sizes. When I try to use callback, the model takes a long time to load, then execution stops abruptly as an output by sys.exit () without error codes and in my terminal.

```
*** Error in `/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python': free(): invalid size: 0x0000000021b35840 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6(+0x7c503)[0x7f80fe3cf503]
/home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi65.so(+0x2ffb6b)[0x7f80d3cf7b6b]
/home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi65.so(+0x2baa53)[0x7f80d3cb2a53]
/home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi65.so(+0x2b7d8d)[0x7f80d3cafd8d]
/home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi65.so(+0x2a68b2)[0x7f80d3c9e8b2]
/home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi65.so(+0x3cee24)[0x7f80d3dc6e24]
/home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi65.so(GRBoptimize+0xf1)[0x7f80d3dc53e1]
/home/abdoisso/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gurobipy/gurobipy.so(+0x65f57)[0x7f80d4afef57]
/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyObject_Call+0x53)[0x7f80ff081333]
/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x4c42)[0x7f80ff1304b2]
/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x88e)[0x7f80ff132dbe]
/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(PyEval_EvalFrameEx+0x5b8a)[0x7f80ff1313fa]
…
…
…
/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/../lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0(Py_Main+0xca4)[0x7f80ff1688f4]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5)[0x7f80fe374b35]
/home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python[0x400649]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 00:2f 10581396  /home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python2.7
00600000-00601000 rw-p 00000000 00:2f 10581396  /home/x86_64-unknown-linux_ol7-gnu/anaconda-2.3.0/bin/python2.7
021f9000-1adbd9000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                 [heap]
7f7e95336000-7f7f84a3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f7f84a3c000-7f80440bd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 99  /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
…
…
…
7f80a6f24000-7f80a7123000 ---p 0000c000 08:03 1610618299                 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f80a7123000-7f80a7124000 r--p 0000b000 08:03 1610618299                 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f80a7124000-7f80a7125000 rw-p 0000c000 08:03 1610618299                 /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.17.so
7f80a7125000-7f80aae2b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f80d3278000-7f80d39f8000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f80d39f8000-7f80d4831000 r-xp 00000000 00:30 40998  /home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi.so.6.5.2
7f80d4831000-7f80d4a31000 ---p 00e39000 00:30 40998     /home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi.so.6.5.2
7f80d4a31000-7f80d4a56000 rw-p 00e39000 00:30 40998    /home/gurobi/6.5.2/linux64/lib/libgurobi.so.6.5.2
7f80d4a56000-7f80d4a99000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
...
```

Comment: It is not normal to get a segmentation fault with the Gurobi Python interface. Please try again with the current version (7.5.2). If that fails, contact us at Gurobi directly.

Comment: M.Greg Glockner, Thanks, i change gurobi version and it is ok.